# Does an in-line boolean return statement evaluate an if condition?

Tags: java, syntax

Could I do...

```
return  (SomeClass.SomeInt > 0);
```

...instead of...

```
if (SomeClass.SomeInt > 0)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

...to return the Boolean value that the if statement evaluated?
I know that it compiles, but I don't really know if that will work, or if there are any disadvantages to using it.

Comment: I don't really know, and my testing environment is currently not accessible. I will post my results when I am able to test this, for others to see.

Comment: `return` returns the result of the given expression, no matter if it is just a literal/constamt (second case) or an expression like `someInt > 0`

Comment: Down-voting for lack of research. A very simple test program would have answered it.

Comment: Please read the comment that says "my testing environment is currently not accessible".

Comment: Quoting down-vote tooltip: *This question does not show any research effort.* StackOverflow is not about giving you immediate answers, it's about answering questions that don't already have answers. It is not a replacement for doing your own research.

Comment: I guess you could be right....But you don't know if I had done other internet research. You make quick assumptions. Anyways....I'm done with this argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of the `return` value would be a `boolean`.  There's no `if` statement to evaluate in your first form, whereas the second form has dedicated `if` statements to evaluate before it elects to return a `boolean`.

In many IDEs and many shops, returning the first form is preferable, because it's much easier to read and its intent is clearer.  In other words, you don't do more work to return the same `boolean`; if `SomeClass.SomeInt > 0`, you'll get `true` or `false` with less fuss.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. It will work.
It's actually better style than the `if-else` option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it and it's cleaner too.  In addition to other answers you can also do it using ternery operators if you want to return something else instead of true/false.

```
return i> 10? b : c;
```